# Json.Net Deserialize complex object

Tags: c#, .net, json, json.net

I have issue with deserialize JSON for next classes:

```
public class Players:List<Player>
{
}

public class Player
{
    public Player()
    {
       PlayerTeam = new Team();
    } 

    public int PlayerId { get; set; }
    public Team PlayerTeam { get; set; } 
}

public class Team
{
    public int TeamId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Result for Team object is always TeamId:0 and Name:null. DataContractJsonSerializer working for this example good, but Json.Net no. why? what I need change in my code, because I must to use Json.Net in my program?

Comment: what's your sample json?

Comment: {
  "PlayerId": 3,
  "PlayerTeam":
      {
        "TeamId": 20,
        "Name": "ABC"
      }
}

Comment: I can't reproduce your issue `var json = "{ \"PlayerId\": 3, \"PlayerTeam\": { \"TeamId\": 20, \"Name\": \"ABC\" } }";
                var obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Player>(json);
                Console.WriteLine($"{obj.PlayerId}, {obj.PlayerTeam.TeamId} - {obj.PlayerTeam.Name}");` Please, provide [Minimal Complete Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: please try next:
`var json = "[{ \"PlayerId\": 3, \"PlayerTeam\": { \"TeamId\": 20, \"Name\": \"ABC\" } },{ \"PlayerId\": 4, \"PlayerTeam\": { \"TeamId\": 21, \"Name\": \"ABCD\" } }]"; var obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Players>(json); Console.WriteLine($"{obj[0].PlayerId}, {obj[0].PlayerTeam.TeamId} - {obj[0].PlayerTeam.Name}");`

Comment: [Seems to work fine](https://dotnetfiddle.net/5n7K78) for me.

Answer (score 1):

This work well :

```
 static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Player player = new Player
            {
                PlayerTeam = new Team { Name ="ABC", TeamId= 20 }, PlayerId = 3
            };


            string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(player, Formatting.Indented);

            Console.WriteLine(json);

            Player player_Des = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Player>(json);

            Console.WriteLine(player_Des.PlayerTeam.Name);

            Console.ReadLine();
        }
```

I prefer this Player Class

```
public class Player
{
    public Player()
    {
    } 

    public int PlayerId { get; set; }
    public Team PlayerTeam { get; set; } 
}
```

hope it helps

Comment: thank you. yes. this example is working, but in my program where classes have other structure this is not working

Comment: in my program I have a structure like this:

public Players:List<Player>
{
}
public class Player
{
    public Player()
    {
       PlayerTeam = new Team();
    } 

    public int PlayerId { get; set; }
    public Team PlayerTeam { get; set; } 
}

public class Team
{
    public int TeamId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

Comment: let me get a look inside

Comment: I can not. please try this code:
`var json = "[{ \"PlayerId\": 3, \"PlayerTeam\": { \"TeamId\": 20, \"Name\": \"ABC\" } },{ \"PlayerId\": 4, \"PlayerTeam\": { \"TeamId\": 21, \"Name\": \"ABCD\" } }]"; var obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Players>(json); Console.WriteLine($"{obj[0].PlayerId}, {obj[0].PlayerTeam.TeamId} - {obj[0].PlayerTeam.Name}");`

Comment: It work fine for me , i edited your question. I just not used  Console.WriteLine($"{obj[0].PlayerId}, {obj[0].PlayerTeam.TeamId} - {obj[0].PlayerTeam.Name}"); instead i used :  Console.WriteLine(obj[1].PlayerId);
            Console.WriteLine(obj[1].PlayerTeam.TeamId);

            Console.WriteLine(obj[1].PlayerTeam.Name);

Answer (score 1):

Still no. I can't reproduce the issue.

```
public class Players : List<Player>
{
}

public class Player
{
    public Player()
    {
        PlayerTeam = new Team();
    }

    public int PlayerId { get; set; }
    public Team PlayerTeam { get; set; }
}

public class Team
{
    public int TeamId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

...

```
var json = "[{ \"PlayerId\": 3, \"PlayerTeam\": { \"TeamId\": 20, \"Name\": \"ABC\" } },{ \"PlayerId\": 4, \"PlayerTeam\": { \"TeamId\": 21, \"Name\": \"ABCD\" } }]";
var players = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Players>(json);

foreach (var player in players)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"{player.PlayerId}, {player.PlayerTeam.TeamId} - {player.PlayerTeam.Name}");
}
```

Prints:

> 3, 20 - ABC
>
> 4, 21 - ABCD

**Perhaps you use some old version of Newtonsoft.Json?**

Comment: I'm using version 4.5.0.0

Comment: @MarianMelnychuk Can you reproduce the issue with the code in my post?

Comment: @MarianMelnychuk 4.5.0.0? If neither of us checks something wrong, then it is a very old version - [the current one is 8.0.2](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Newtonsoft.Json/).

Comment: just use this shell :  Install-Package Newtonsoft.Json